# Ways to parse image loaded with Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, web-crawler

Are there any smooth ways to get image which is loaded with javascript? Possibly with PHP.
Let me explain a litle more: I wan't to get one picture from website but it is loaded with JS so i cant get it with url or via dom, because JS need to be executed. So I want to know if there are any ways to do that with PHP, if not, any language or method is acceptable

Comment: PHP is server-side, JS is client-side. Unless you're implementing a JS interpreter within PHP, you can't run the JS code via a server-side PHP script.

Comment: I know php is server and js client site language.... beter you tell me how to implement it

Comment: You want to find a headless browser that can run JavaScript so you can screenscrape.

Comment: That Javascript is still loading the image via a URL, it's just that the URL is not in the HTML.